# Snake Game Not Working -JavaScript For Kids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was racking my head for a whole night trying to figure out why my code isn't working. I copied the code 2 times but the result was the same. The problem was sometimes when the snake eats an apple, it doesn't work. The snake would just go by the apple like it was not there. Please help me with this, I want to get it done. (I added jQuery)

```
`
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

var score = 0;

var drawBorder = function () {
ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};

var drawScore = function () {
ctx.font = "20px Courier";
ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
};

var gameOver = function () {
clearInterval(intervalId);
ctx.font = "60px Courier";
ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
};

var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
} else {
    ctx.stroke();
}
};

var Block = function (col, row) {
this.col = col;
this.row = row;
};

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
var x = this.col * blockSize;
var y = this.row * blockSize;
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function (color) {
var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = color;
circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};

Block.prototype.equal = function (otherBlock) {
return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};


var Snake = function () {
this.segments = [
new Block(7, 5),
new Block(6, 5),
new Block(5, 5)
];
this.direction = "right";
this.nextDirection = "right";
};

Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
}
};


Snake.prototype.move = function () {
var head = this.segments[0];
var newHead;

this.direction = this.nextDirection;

if (this.direction === "right") {
newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
} else if (this.direction === "down") {
newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
} else if (this.direction === "left") {
newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
} else if (this.direction === "up") {
newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
}

if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
gameOver();
return;
}

this.segments.unshift(newHead);

if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
score++;
apple.move();
} else {
this.segments.pop();
};
};

Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
var bottomCollision = (head.row === widthInBlocks - 1);

var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision ||           bottomCollision;

var selfCollision = false;

for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
        selfCollision = true;
    }
}

return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
} else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
} else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
} else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
}

this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};

var Apple = function () {
this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};

Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};


Apple.prototype.move = function () {
var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};

var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
drawScore();
snake.move();
snake.draw();
apple.draw();
drawBorder();
}, 100);

var directions = {
37: "left",
38: "up",
39: "right",
40: "down"
};

$("body").keydown(function (event) {
var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
}
});
`
```

Comment: Here you go everybody: http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/3629/

Comment: never mind everybody i found the freaking answer finally. -_-

Comment: It's in the Block.prototype.drawCircle part

Comment: I accidentally created to .col

Comment: yuuup. silly mistake.

Comment: It happens, and very common.  lol  Cool to see a gaming post related to javascript.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the source to his project? Like is posted on Github or anywhere? I been wanting to get into gaming jscript as hobby and would be interested to see.

Comment: I got the code from a book called: Javascript For Kids -Nick Morgan.

Comment: You can also get the book from safaribooksonline

Comment: yeah so achievement get!

Comment: If you have an answer, provide it below and accept it. If not, please delete your question as it has no value to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
//// Set up canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// // Get the width and height from the canvas element
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

//// Work out the width and height in blocks
var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

// // Set score to 0
var score = 0;

// // Draw the border
var drawBorder = function () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};

// // Draw the score in the top-left corner
var drawScore = function () {
  ctx.font = "20px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
};

// // Clear the interval and display Game Over text
var gameOver = function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
};

// // Draw a circle (using the function from Chapter 14)
var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

// // The Block constructor
var Block = function (col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};

// // Draw a square at the block's location
Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};

// // Draw a circle at the block's location
Block.prototype.drawCircle = function (color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};

// // Check if this block is in the same location as another block
Block.prototype.equal = function (otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};

// // The Snake constructor
var Snake = function () {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];

  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};

// // Draw a square for each segment of the snake's body
Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.segments[0].drawSquare("LimeGreen");
  var isEvenSegment = false;

  for (var i = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (isEvenSegment) {
      this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
    } else {
      this.segments[i].drawSquare("Yellow");
    }

    isEvenSegment = !isEvenSegment; // следующий сегмент будет нечетным
  }
};

// // Create a new head and add it to the beginning of
// the snake to move the snake in its current direction
Snake.prototype.move = function () {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;

  this.direction = this.nextDirection;

  if (this.direction === "right") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "down") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === "left") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "up") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }

  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};

// // Check if the snake's new head has collided with the wall or itself
Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }

  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};

// // Set the snake's next direction based on the keyboard
Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
  }

  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};

// // The Apple constructor
var Apple = function () {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};

//  // Draw a circle at the apple's location
Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};

// // Move the apple to a new random location
Apple.prototype.move = function () {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};

// // Create the snake and apple objects
var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

//// Pass an animation function to setInterval
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);

// // Convert keycodes to directions
var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

// // The keydown handler for handling direction key presses
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This one is working

Comment: You need to mention what's specially done here which makes it work, or different from the ones already proposed